# MySQL: Select Most Recent Response By Max Date from JOINing Tables

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, max

I have a survey table that compiles non-unique records whenever that person responds to a survey, so they can be in there multiple times -- I'm trying to figure out how to bring back the just the row with the most recent date.

Here's the `person` table:

```
ID  First   Last     Employer
1   Jerry   Seinfeld NBC
2   Elaine  Benes    Pendant Publishing
3   George  Costanza Kruger Industrial Smoothing
4   Cosmo   Kramer   Kramerica Industries
```

And here's the `survey` table:

```
ID  Survey  Response Date
1   9       Yes      4/14/15
1   9       No       8/9/15
2   9       No       10/13/15
3   9       No       6/19/15
3   9       Yes      2/3/15
3   8       IQ       7/27/15
4   9       Yes      5/12/15
```

If the IDs duplicate and the survey number is 9, I only want returned the row with the most recent date.

Here's what I've been trying:

```
SELECT p.id, p.first, p.last, p.employer, s.response, s.date
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT s1.id, s1.survey, s1.response, s1.date, MAX(s1.date)
     FROM survey s1
     WHERE s1.survey = 9
     GROUP BY s1.id) AS s ON s.id = p.id
ORDER BY s.date;
```

But whenever I do that the max date and the actual date for the row don't match sometimes -- so the `MAX` function is working correctly but only with regards to the ID, not with regards to giving me that row. But I have to group on the ID in order to properly match the two tables and that's where I'm getting stuck.

And when I try something like this I get the `Invalid use of group function` error:

```
SELECT p.id, p.first, p.last, p.employer, s.response, s.date
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT s1.id, s1.survey, s1.response, s1.date, MAX(s1.date)
     FROM survey s1
     WHERE s1.survey = 9 AND MAX(s1.date) = s1.date
     GROUP BY s1.id) AS s ON s.id = p.id
ORDER BY s.date;
```

My desired result looks like this:

```
ID  First   Last     Employer                    Response   Date
3   George  Costanza Kruger Industrial Smoothing Yes        2/3/15
4   Cosmo   Kramer   Kramerica Industries        Yes        5/12/15
1   Jerry   Seinfeld NBC                         No         8/9/15
2   Elaine  Benes    Pendant Publishing          No         10/13/15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is tested query:

```
select `person`.*,`survey`.`Response`,`survey`.`Date`
from `survey`
inner join 
    (
      SELECT ID,max(`Date`) as `d`
      FROM `survey` 
      WHERE `Survey`=9
      group by ID
    ) as `t` on `t`.`ID` = `survey`.`ID` and 
      `t`.`d` = `survey`.`Date`
inner join `person` on `person`.`ID` = `survey`.`ID`
```